# Why do I get these errors "Data truncated for column"?

Tags: python, csv, insert, mysql-python

I use this string to upload my CSV file into a MySQL table.

```
Query = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Data to file_name.csv' INTO TABLE table_name
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
    Lines terminated by '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES """
cursor.execute(Query)
```

Everything works great but I get this error message for two date type columns:

> Data truncated for column start_date

and

> Data truncated for column end_date

Sometimes I have the date format "start_date" like this "1-Dec-2012" and "end_date" is like "1-12-2012". How can I do a big insert from a CSV file and not receive the "Data truncated for column start date and end date error message"?

Does anyone have any idea why this error is generated? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you provide the table definition and the contents of a single line CSV file that exhibits the problem.

Comment: sounds like great idea! I was thinking about leveraging the function ` LOAD DATA LOCAL` to make it easy, but seems like I have to go with the other way. Thanks a lot @dansalmo